# How to change name attribute of a hidden field?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a hidden field on my aspx page and I use masterpage.
Without using masterpage everything is fine and name attribute of hiddenfield is correct.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="apiversion" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

After rendering, result html is;

```
<input type="hidden" name="apiversion" id="apiversion" value="v0.01">
```

But if use masterpage then result html is being like;

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$apiversion" id="apiversion" value="v0.01">
```

But I have to use masterpage and need name attribute as 'apiversion', not as 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$apiversion'.

Any solution?

Comment: Why exactly would you change that ? What is the problem you're facing ?

Comment: I call a service that gets values from my request page. But service cannot read my hiddenfields while I am using masterpage. So I need to change name attr of hidden field as I wish.

Comment: You have same value of name and id why don't you use id?

Comment: 3rd party webservice is taking name value. It's not in my control.

Comment: You should gather info from you codebehind and call the service from there then cause as far as I know there's no way to change that, it is by design.
If you don't need to access the field from codebehind though, you can use directly the HTML control with no runat server so that you keep total control on it

Comment: quick and dirty would be to change it with javascript after page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but i think this should work... Change the name attribute at document ready..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%=apiversion.ClientID%>").attr("name","apiversion");
});
```

Alternatively..

```
var arrayOfNames=[];
var actualName=$("#<%=apiversion.ClientID%>").attr("name");
arrayOfNames=actualName.split('$');

var whatYouActuallyWant=arrayOfNames[2];// This is the name you have without master page.
```

Keeping the comment below in consideration.. In case of partial postbacks like in case of update panel, add a pageLoad function...

```
function pageLoad(sender,args){
     $("#<%=apiversion.ClientID%>").attr("name","apiversion");
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you try to access the hidden value from code behind after a POST, it probably won't work.

Comment: thanks @writeToBhuwan, it works great :) using javascript is great solution for me :)